# Set multiple app views for many modules in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, mean, meanjs

I have my code

```
app.set('views', path..);
```

originally placed in `server.js` and I tried to segregate/factor it into a [config.server.js](https://github.com/zenithtekla/nodeMySQL/blob/master/config/config.server.js#L13) (see link), there I implemented `underscoreJS` each to loop through the modules by their folders' names in my `modules/` directory. ['core', 'xt_syncs']. Problem with this trick I try playing is that, `app.set('views',..)` can't be a Singleton (which loads many things at once). The `app.set('views',..)` can only have 1 URI for 'views' (module specific, my app contains several modules: core, xt_syncs as you see in the structure), and the `app.set` appear to fail, and be overwritten by the static uri to modules/second_module.

I write the app myself, picking the middlewares/components I want. I'm trying to reuse some of the assets from MEANjs, mean-stack-relational (MVC, I prefer modules architecture to MVC, that's why my attempt is to build mine), and SEANjs (quite too complex, the stack requires Redis and MySQL5.7, I try building mine so I can get a good understanding of things flow on the fly and exclude Redis and MySQL upgrade).

Now back to the question, obviously, you see in [MEANjs](https://github.com/zenithtekla/yo-std-mean-emi/blob/master/config/assets/default.js#L55) and [SEANjs](https://github.com/zenithtekla/seanjs_emi/blob/master/config/assets/default.js#L39) , they do in their default.js file:

```
views: ['modules/*/client/views/**/*.html'],

routes: ['modules/!(core)/server/routes/**/*.js', 'modules/core/server/routes/**/*.js']
```

**QUESTIONS**:

1/ How can I implement similar pattern in my app? **Notice in the MEANjs and SEANjs, there is `*` as in `modules/*/client` and `!` as in `modules/!(core)/server`. app design advices and coding help, please.** (*this part of the question is not yet addressed*)

2/ How related the `default.js` is to the [config.js](https://github.com/zenithtekla/seanjs_emi/blob/master/config/config.js) (initGlobalConfigFolders,initGlobalConfigFiles,...)? I try to wrap my head around to understand config.js and find clues of the glueing. Maybe, my modules[module] as in

```
modules[module] = {
        client: {},
        server: {}
};
```

is one step closer to what they built in the initGlobalConfigFolders method.

3/ Is using build tool (Grunt, Gulp, or Webpack) a must here to achieve that? If so, Can you show me how? (build tool incorporation is in my planning). How can you

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. This [patch](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/2320) hinted at implementing `app.set('views', view_paths);` // where view_paths can be an array of views folders.

2 & 3. Awaiting help and answers.